# Vim fails to set omnifunction with clang

Tags: c++, vim, clang, omnicomplete

I understand that clang can be used in place of omnicppcomplete.  However, after installing clang, vim fails to autocomplete on scripts specified in the vimrc.  i.e. previously, `autocmd FileType python set omnifunc     = pythoncomplete#Complete` in the .vimrc file worked fine.

After installing clang, however, it returns this error whenever I open a file:

```
Error detected while processing FileType Auto commands for "python":
E518: Unknown option: pythoncomplete#Complete
```

I tried to remove the clang directory as well, but the error remains.  Any idea?

EDIT: Realized after much debugging that you can't leave spaces between the '=' sign.  So the proper method would be '`autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete`'.

Comment: Isn't clang_complete limited to C, C++ and Objective C? How do you wish to complete Python with it?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it so that people (and machines) will know that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Vim treats the `pythoncomplete#Complete` as another setting (that does not exist), because you've accidentally included a space around the `=`. You can change multiple settings with the `:set` command.